# How can I fetch data in server before render in react isomorphic app?

Tags: reactjs

I found some aproaches, but they don't work with react-router version 4. It's really strange, there is no any information about that in documentations.

Comment: https://blog.tableflip.io/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-redux/ - I solved my problem after reading this article.

Answer (score 2):

Answering this in 2019 because seems like there is no clear answer yet.

If your backend services are using GraphQL, you can actually just use `react-apollo` and you can then declare your data requirement in the component itself. The SSR process is very simple since `react-apollo` just provide function like `renderToStringWithData()` or `getDataFromTree()` to automatically fetch all the data in your component tree.

But, if you are not using graphql, but just simple fetch GET request, I don't think there were any solution like `react-apollo`. Recently, I wrote [`react-isomorphic-data`](https://react-isomorphic-data.netlify.com/) for this use case. You can declare the data requirement for your components inside each components itself, and it provides function for SSR supports as well, similar to `react-apollo`.

The library is still young, but I think it's worth to try. If you have feedback feel free to create an issue on [github](https://github.com/jackyef/react-isomorphic-data).

Answer (score 1):

Things must have changed since, but back in 2015 I wrote an article about that. You can read it [here](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/going-isomorphic-with-reactjs-and-flux-73873a2f7f8)

The main idea is to wrap your action into promise. Server side you must call the appropriate action ( depending on the route ) and wait for the promise to fulfill before calling `React.renderToString()` ( which is synchronous ). Then you need to find a way to synchronize state computed by server with the client to avoid doing the same request for nothing. In the article, I explain I pass the state into the window object.

But again it was in 2015, it may be outdated.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can see my [react-ssr-startkit](https://github.com/zedwang/react-ssr-startkit).

client:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
// some logic
}
Home.serverFetch = {type: 'repos/fetchData'};
```

server:

```
routes
.filter(route => matchPath(req.url, route))
.map(route => route.component)
.filter(comp => comp.serverFetch)
.map(comp => {
    const {type, payload} = comp.serverFetch;
    return dispatch({type, payload});
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) inside your constructor, according to the react [Lifecycles](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html), constructor came before the render();

Example:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
    axios.get('http://into-the-feed-api.cloud.globoi.com/') 
    .then(res => {
      const index = this.getIndex(res.data);
      if (index) {
        this.setState({
          items: [res.data[index]].concat(res.data.slice(0, index).concat(res.data.slice(index + 1, res.data.length)) ),
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({ items: res.data }); 
      } 
    });
    this.changeHeaderExpanded = this.changeHeaderExpanded.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: And...? Axios returns promise, not data itself. If I open html-code of page, there is no any data from API. Understand? But I need this data in html (in html from server)!

Answer (score -2):

You need to fetch the data on your webserver, then pass along the data to your (dumb) component which will only render and not do to much logic.

If you need to update the data on the clientside, look into a socket solution or just create an interval fetch in componentdidmount().

We're currently looking into this and we're using Airbnb's Hypernova to handle the universal rendering, the thing is you still need a webserver to allow components to map with a url which we can cache and server side include into our page.
So in that webserver you could do the fetch and pass, so you get an initial state of your component as html.